# Maven project source encoding does not work

Tags: java, maven, encoding, utf-8

I am having a Maven-Project which is configured using the following properties:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

On my machine everything works fine with these settings. However, on another machine, when I check it out and try to build it using `mvn install` the compiler errors `unmappable character for encoding ASCII`:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project scuttle: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /export/local-1/julian-downloads/scuttle/src/main/java/de/fu/mi/scuttle/handlers/sakai/SakaiVV.java:[99,39] error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] /export/local-1/julian-downloads/scuttle/src/main/java/de/fu/mi/scuttle/handlers/sakai/SakaiVV.java:[99,40] error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] /export/local-1/julian-downloads/scuttle/src/main/java/de/fu/mi/scuttle/domain/sakai/SakvvTermin.java:[66,30] error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] /export/local-1/julian-downloads/scuttle/src/main/java/de/fu/mi/scuttle/domain/sakai/SakvvTermin.java:[66,31] error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII
```

I've already tried running `mvn` with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` but that did not help. `$LC_CTYPE` reports `UTF-8`.

What can I do?

You can see the complete pom file here: https://github.com/scravy/scuttle/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your sources are UTF-8 encoded? Possibly, they are not, but it works in your environment for some reason (maybe your IDE interferes)

Comment: Please update your maven-compiler-version cause 2.0.2 is really old. Currently we have 3.1..

Comment: Have same issue with default maven-compiler plug-in v2.0.2. Increasing version solve issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the end the comment by khmarbaise helped me find a solution:

I configured the compiler plugin and specified the source encoding there, now everything works everywhere:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Great that you found the solution to your problem yourself !

Answer (score 2):

You have all the right settings in your pom, so that's good. Verify your IDE (and the others used by your team if applicable) is configured for UTF-8.

Next, clean out your local `.m2` repository and run your build again. It might be possible one of your transitive dependencies wasn't compiled with the right encoding. But you may have the "right" version in your `.m2` that makes everything OK while the same version doesn't exist on the other machine.

Good luck! I know how annoying this stuff can be.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting `maven` opts, set new environmental variable - `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF8`